# Selenium only opening and directly closing the browser

Tags: java, selenium, browser, cucumber

I am writing a basic Cucumber test with Selenium integrated I want to open a site login and check if i have logged in. The problem is in the first step of the test firefox is opend and closed imediatly and the test runs indefinitely.
[Here you can see my map structure all the other maps are empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Usvw.png)

```
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class CucumberRunner {
}
```

this is my runner class

```
Feature: To If i can login

  Scenario: Check if login is complete
    Given I am on the  website
    When I click on login
    And Populate the contact form
    Then I should be on the account page
```

This is my feature

```
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertTrue;


public class StepDefinitions {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @Given("^I am on the  website$")
    public void ShouldnavigateToWebsite(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        System.out.println("voor");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.out.println("na");
        driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");
    }


    @When("^I click on login$")
    public void ClickOnLink(){
        driver.findElement(By.id("account")).click();
    }

    @And("^Populate the contact form$")
    public void PopulateForms(){
        driver.findElement(By.id("log")).sendKeys("TimoTest");
        driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("TimoTest1");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
    }

    @Then("^I should be on the account page$")
    public void ShouldBeOnContactPage(){
        assertTrue("Not one account page",driver.getTitle().equals("your-account"));
    }
}
```

And here is the test itself.
The the only thing that he prints is voor (Before).

Comment: Is your code commented on the machine you're running?

Comment: Before i had the commented code running and commented it to see if it helped. It did not and it does no get past the assignee driver so it does not run

Comment: So the `"na"` isn't printed? And Firefox is opened and closed right away?

Comment: yes( and na means after in dutch)

Comment: Your problem is with the `new FirefoxDriver()`, look for the specific exception.

Comment: if you are starting new project from scratch, You should try using [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/). Here is [qaf-step-by-step-tutorial](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-step-by-step-tutorial/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is with versions. Open Firefox without Selenium to see it doesn't have updates pending. If it has, update to last version. And make sure you use latest `selenium-java` which is 3.0.1. Hope it fixes your issue.